# ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR: DTOs cause hub method failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, auth0

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR application, but I have fallen at the first hurdle. Ok, it's the fifth hurdle.

My hub looks like this:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
  public async Task SendMessage(object profile)
  {
    doSomethingWithProfile(profile);
  }
}
```

which works fine, since I am using an `object` type. I would like, however, to use a strongly-typed DTO, like this:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
  public async Task SendMessage(ProfileDTO profile)
  {
    doSomethingWithProfile(profile);
  }
}
```

However, the method is never called when I use this type, even though I am absolutely sure the `profile` object matches the shape of the data being passed into it:

```
public class ProfileDTO
{
  public string given_name { get; set; }
  public string family_name { get; set; }
  public string nickname { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string picture { get; set; }
  public string locale { get; set; }
  public string updated_at { get; set; }
  public string email { get; set; }
  public string email_verified { get; set; }
  public string sub { get; set; }
}
```

I am sure this is a very simple configuration option, but I don't know how! Can anyone help?

---

## UPDATE

I am able to convert it to the DTO like this:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
  public async Task SendMessage(object user)
  {
    ProfileDTO profileDto = ((JsonElement)user).ToObject<ProfileDTO>();
     
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user);
  }
}

public static class JsonElementExtensions
{
  public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element)
  {
    var json = element.GetRawText();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
  }
  public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonDocument document)
  {
    var json = document.RootElement.GetRawText();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
  }
}
```

...but this seems like an awful lot of jumping through hoops. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Maybe it is because of serialization... Have you tried this? 
`services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = // your policy here
    });
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that property names is the problem in ProfileDTO. Property names starts with lowercase which causes binding issues.

Comment: Is there a way to configure SignalR to allow these properties to remain lowercased? It makes no sense to me, in my app, to capitalise them.